# How to get String output as in single quote in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Advance thanks, Question looks like simple but i could not able to find the solution.

```
function sumStrings(a, b)
{
return  +a + +b;
}
sumStrings('1','2') //=>3
```

Expected output

```
sumStrings('1','2') // => '3'
```

Comment: Try this `console.log("x='5'");`

Comment: You could try to convert it to string:  var n = x.toString();

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve... `x='5'` or `x="5"` in JavaScript have the same result... You are talking about a form? I don't see any form...

Comment: Thanks Hassan,I have modified the question

Answer (score 2):

After addition, add `'` to beginning and end.

```js
function sumStrings(a, b){
  
  return  "'" + (Number(a) + Number(b)) + "'";
}
console.log(sumStrings('1','2'));
```

Comment: Looks good the expected result will shown in  console,But if i call the functionn like sumStrings('1','2'); it returns "'3'" ,How can we make it as '3'

Comment: @murthynaikak Where are you storing the result?

Comment: I am not storing anywhere actually i was executing in console so it treats as a string,the same if i place in my js file it works as per my expectation.
I have one more query is
How can i achieve the result like this

sumStrings('50095301248058391139327916261', '81055900096023504197206408605') // => '131151201344081895336534324866'

Comment: In console if you execute `sumStrings('50095301248058391139327916261', '81055900096023504197206408605') ` then it would return `"'1.3115120134408189e+29'"`. `""` signifies the returned result is string. So, your output is correct, it's just browser way of telling a string.

Comment: You are correct
    sumStrings('50095301248058391139327916261', 
    '81055900096023504197206408605') then it would return 
    "'1.3115120134408189e+29'" ,I dont want exponential .i want the result should be 
    '131151201344081895336534324866'

Comment: `function toFix(i){
 var str='';
 do{
   let a = i%10;
   i=Math.trunc(i/10);
   str = a+str;
 }while(i>0)
 return str;
}` to convert exponent to string.

Answer (score 1):

```
function sumStrings(a, b) {
    // Separate decimal part here
    var pointa = a.indexOf(".");
    var pointb = b.indexOf(".");
    var deca = pointa != -1 ? a.substring(pointa + 1) : "0";
    var decb = pointb != -1 ? b.substring(pointb + 1) : "0";

    if (deca.length < decb.length)
        deca += (Math.pow(10, decb.length - deca.length)).toString().substring(1);
    else
        decb += (Math.pow(10, deca.length - decb.length)).toString().substring(1);

    var inta = pointa != -1 ? a.substring(0, pointa) : a;
    var intb = pointb != -1 ? b.substring(0, pointb) : b;
    // console.log(deca + " " + decb);
    var decc = addBigInt(deca, decb);
    var intc = addBigInt(inta, intb);

    if (decc.length > deca.length) {
        intc = addBigInt(intc, "1");
        decc = decc.substring(1);
    }

    var lastZero = decc.length - 1;
    while (lastZero >= 0 && decc[lastZero] == "0") {
        lastZero--;
    }

    if (lastZero >= 0)
        return intc + "." + decc.substring(0, lastZero + 1);
    else
        return intc;
}

function addBigInt(a, b) {
    var inda = a.length - 1;
    var indb = b.length - 1;
    var c = [];
    const zero = "0".charCodeAt(0);
    var carry = 0;
    var sum = 0;

    while (inda >= 0 && indb >= 0) {
        var d1 = a.charCodeAt(inda--) - zero;
        var d2 = b.charCodeAt(indb--) - zero;

        sum = (d1 + d2 + carry);
        carry = Math.floor(sum / 10);
        sum %= 10;
        c.unshift(sum);
    }

    if (inda >= 0) {
        while (carry && inda >= 0) {
            sum = a.charCodeAt(inda--) - zero + carry;
            c.unshift(sum % 10);
            carry = Math.floor(sum / 10);
        }
        c.unshift(a.substring(0, inda + !carry));
    } else {
        while (carry && indb >= 0) {
            sum = b.charCodeAt(indb--) - zero + carry;
            c.unshift(sum % 10);
            carry = Math.floor(sum / 10);
        }
        c.unshift(b.substring(0, indb + !carry));
    }

    if (carry)
        c.unshift(carry);
    return c.join("");
}
  console.log(sumStrings("1","2"));
  console.log(sumStrings("800","9567"));
  console.log(sumStrings("99.1","1"));
  console.log(sumStrings("00103","08567"));
  console.log(sumStrings("50095301248058391139327916261.5","81055900096023504197206408605"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to escape the single quote, you can try to add a backslash before the single quote.
i.e.

```
var x = '\'5\'';
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans ,But still
var x = '\'5\'';
x
"'5'" ,i am expecting output as '5'

Answer (score 0):

With the new template literal you can try this:

```
a=`'5'`;
console.log(a);
```